# How to check each row click on the specific value in uipath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I have been working around a SAP table where, I have to find an specific string inside the column (Direction) of an table in SAP UI.

The String value is dynamic and the location also keeps on changing in the column every month so can’t use the click activity,

Is there any way so as to find the string and use the click activity on it

```
S.No     Name     Direction
1        Liu       North
2        Sam       NorthEast
3       Jack       NorthWest
4       Daren      South
5       Will       East
```

**For Eg:**
Need to find southWest in the Direction column and double click on it.